# What's the range of Magneto's powers?

Tags: marvel, x-men, magneto

As the summary says, is the range of Magneto's powers mentioned anywhere?

Comment: I would state his range to be.... 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How does it sound "between 628,743,036 million km and 928,081,020 million km apart"? (In astronomical units the distance varies from 4.2 AU to 6.2 AU.)

In the events of "[Avengers vs X-Men](http://is.gd/bz4VII)" the one and only Magneto took the magnetic attraction energy from the big 'ol planet Jupiter (yes, the planet!) in order to fight Iron-Man. Which means its maximum known range of powers is [the distance between the Earth and Jupiter](http://www.universetoday.com/14514/how-far-is-jupiter-from-earth/#ixzz2F3EpIHq8).

Comment: Technically the Wiki says: During the battle on Utopia, Iron Man gains the upper hand in his fight with Magneto by siphoning magnetic energy from Jupiter. It goes on to explain that Magneto up the ante by extending his range and magnetic awareness and discovers the approaching Phoenix Force. Just thought you should know...

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that's the *minimum* for the known range of his abilities?

Comment: @Thaddeus Having sat down and read the relevant AvX books, there are some missing details here.  Iron Man does pull some energy from Jupiter, using some Stark satellites.  In return, Magneto pulls power from celestial bodies as well, "You're not the only one who can steal the power of planetary objects.  If you've ever wondered what it would feel like to be bludgeoned with a sun... Prepare to learn."  Magneto then notices a planet that the Phoenix destroyed.  Except that planet was *in a different solar system.*

Answer (score 5):

**Magneto powers are widely described and in often conflicting in the descriptions, so there is little documentation about the range of his powers. With that said, there are things writers typically infer about Magneto's abilities. Each writers interpretation of the character varies.**

- Since Magneto can find and access the magnetism from the Earth, anywhere ON the Earth, he has proven he can manipulate and even alter the magnetic field of the Earth, with considerable effort. He altered Earth's magnetic field permanently trying to reduce the range or effectiveness of Charles Xavier's (Professor X) telepathy ability, for example.
- He is able to utilize or harness magnetic electromagnetic fields even at interplanetary ranges as he does during the AvX storylines. How he does this is NOT explained in any detail. We are forced to accept that interplanetary distances  are no limit to his awareness or ability to manipulate electromagnetic phenomena.
- Magneto can manipulate magnetic fields to generate powerful electromagnetic pulses and can even manipulate photons warping light around himself becoming invisible. He can manipulate the electromagnetic spectrum so that he may generate lightning bolts, emit vast amounts of infrared radiation or even manipulate the force of gravity.
- He is capable of generating electromagnetic barriers capable of resisting nuclear weapons and can exist in deep space using these fields to protect himself from radiation. He is able to propel himself at near-light speeds. He has also been able to generate wormholes to travel through space, teleporting himself and others safely.

Comment: Your second point contains some inaccuracies.  [Interstellar medium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_medium): "Magnetic fields and turbulent motions also provide pressure in the ISM, and are typically more important dynamically than the thermal pressure is."

Comment: Yes, magnetic fields are dynamic, but their dynamic nature did not imply they should be able to be easily manipulated even by the likes of Magneto over interplanetary or even interstellar distances. Most mutants are limited in their ability to interact or utilize their powers at ranges of greater than a few thousand miles. To be able to do so over millions or hundreds of millions of miles is questionable at best.

Comment: I thought I could add something constructive here but this conversation quickly passed me! I was under the impression that he could manipulate ferrous metals within a limited range of about a couple hundred yards. Now I learn he can control planetary electromagnetic fields at interplanetary ranges, bend light and manipulate gravity?! My silver age knowledge obviously means little in light of these new 'discovered' powers. Apperently the question should be, "What can't he do"?

Answer (score 0):

The man gathers energy by the law of attraction. Waves of vibrating magnetic energy should be limitless.